# SQL Lite Studio generated DDL incorrect

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am using sqlLite Studio to create a sql lite database however the ddl it is producing is giving an error I want my primary key to be auto number here is the code and the options i selected

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys = 0;

CREATE TABLE sqlitestudio_temp_table AS SELECT *
                                          FROM ExportProcessed;

DROP TABLE ExportProcessed;

CREATE TABLE ExportProcessed (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, ORDERID INTEGER, PROCESSED BOOLEAN, ProcessedBy STRING, PRIMARY KEY (ID DESC) AUTOINCREMENT);
INSERT INTO ExportProcessed (
                                ID,
                                ORDERID,
                                PROCESSED,
                                ProcessedBy
                            )
                            SELECT ID,
                                   ORDERID,
                                   PROCESSED,
                                   ProcessedBy
                              FROM sqlitestudio_temp_table;

DROP TABLE sqlitestudio_temp_table;

PRAGMA foreign_keys = 1;
```

[image]

Here is the auto increment

[image]

This is the errror message I am getting 
[image]
This is the version of sql lite studio I am using.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to create 2 primary indexes. However, `AUTOINCREMENT` is highlighted as the error *(as `AUTOINCREMENT` can only be specified for a PRIMARY INDEX, which has  already been created internally/theorectically, so cannot now be coded)*.

Removing `AUTOINCREMENT` results in ***table "ExportProcessed" has more than one primary key***.

The fix could be to use :-

```
CREATE TABLE ExportProcessed (ID INTEGER, ORDERID INTEGER, PROCESSED BOOLEAN, ProcessedBy STRING, PRIMARY KEY(ID DESC AUTOINCREMENT));
```

---

#### Additional Consideration

Do you really need or even want `AUTOINCREMENT`? All that `AUTOINCREMENT` does is specify that a different algorithm is used when determining the underlying **rowid** and that the generated **rowid** is greater than the largest used **rowid**.

Not coding `AUTOINCREMENT`, but still defining `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` still results in an automatically generated **rowid** *(which will typically be larger until/if the number of the largest rowid of 9223372036854775807 has been used, after which using `AUTOINCREMENT` will fail with an SQLITE_FULL error, however without an attempt will be made to utilise a free/unused lower value if available)*.

Using `ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` or `ID INTEGER,..., PRIMARY KEY(ID)` with or without `AUTOINCREMENT` makes the column ID an alias of the **rowid** (not normally seen column).

Using `AUTOINCREMENT` has overheads and is not recommended as per :-

> The AUTOINCREMENT keyword imposes extra CPU, memory, disk space, and
>   disk I/O overhead and should be avoided if not strictly needed. It is
>   usually not needed.

[SQLite Autoincrement](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html)

#### `AUTOINCREMENT` v not coding it Example

Consider the following :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ExportProcessedV2;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ExportProcessedV2 (ID INTEGER, ORDERID INTEGER, PROCESSED BOOLEAN, ProcessedBy STRING, PRIMARY KEY(ID DESC));
INSERT INTO ExportProcessedV2 (ORDERID,PROCESSED, PROCESSEDBY) VALUES (100,0,null);
INSERT INTO ExportProcessedV2 (ORDERID,PROCESSED, PROCESSEDBY) VALUES (100,0,null);
INSERT INTO ExportProcessedV2 VALUES(9223372036854775807,100,0,null); -- insert with the highest possible rowid
INSERT INTO ExportProcessedV2 (ORDERID,PROCESSED, PROCESSEDBY) VALUES (100,0,null);
SELECT * FROM ExportProcessedV2;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ExportProcessed;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ExportProcessed (ID INTEGER, ORDERID INTEGER, PROCESSED BOOLEAN, ProcessedBy STRING, PRIMARY KEY(ID DESC AUTOINCREMENT));
INSERT INTO ExportProcessed (ORDERID,PROCESSED, PROCESSEDBY) VALUES (100,0,null);
INSERT INTO ExportProcessed (ORDERID,PROCESSED, PROCESSEDBY) VALUES (100,0,null);
INSERT INTO ExportProcessed VALUES(9223372036854775807,100,0,null); -- insert with the highest possible rowid
INSERT INTO ExportProcessed (ORDERID,PROCESSED, PROCESSEDBY) VALUES (100,0,null);
SELECT * FROM ExportProcessed;
```

The former (V2) **without** `AUTOINCREMENT` works and results in :-

[image]

i.e. after reaching the highest possible rowid a lower free/unused rowid has been used.

However, the latter using `AUTOINCREMENT` fails as per :-

```
INSERT INTO ExportProcessed (ORDERID,PROCESSED, PROCESSEDBY) VALUES (100,0,null)
> database or disk is full
```

and if the inserts or not within a transaction will result in a table :-

[image]

---

#### Additional re SQLite Studio

After installing SQLite Studio and checking a few scenarios the following issues have been found.

**1. Multiple PRIMARY KEYS can be defined per table when only 1 should e.g.** :-

[image]

The generated DDL being (which can't be committed) :-

```
CREATE TABLE EPV1 (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY DESC AUTOINCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY (ID DESC) AUTOINCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY (ID ASC), PRIMARY KEY (ID DESC) AUTOINCREMENT);
```

**2. An SQLite Bug with INTEGER PRIMARY KEY DESC is not handled correctly.

SQLite has a bug as per

> if the declaration of a column with declared type "INTEGER" includes
>   an "PRIMARY KEY DESC" clause, it does not become an alias for the
>   rowid and is not classified as an integer primary key. This quirk is
>   not by design. It is due to a bug in early versions of SQLite. But
>   fixing the bug could result in backwards incompatibilities. Hence, the
>   original behavior has been retained (and documented) because odd
>   behavior in a corner case is far better than a compatibility break.
>   This means that the following three table declarations all cause the
>   column "x" to be an alias for the rowid (an integer primary key):

SQLite Studio if configuring with `AUTOINCREMENT` and sort `DESC` creates DDL as

```
CREATE TABLE EPV1 (
    ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY DESC AUTOINCREMENT
);
```

Dues to the above ID is not an alias for the **rowid** and thus cannot have `AUTOINCREMENT` coded. The correct DDL should be the subtly different :-

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS EPV1 (
    ID INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY (ID DESC AUTOINCREMENT)
);
```

Comment: Mike thanks for ur detailed answer that was indeed the problem but sql lite was creating this ddl once i modified it it was fine.

Comment: @DavidB I don't have/use SQLite Studio (I think I tried it and didn't like it) but it would appear to be a bug in that it's allowing/coding PRIMARY KEY more than once.

Comment: @DavidB installed SQLite Studio and yep it easily allows multiple primary keys. However they cannot be committed. You may wish to raise this as an issue. Could you please tick this as answered.

Comment: @DavidB I've raised an issue regarding this. I've also updated the question in regards to some findings re SQLite Studio.